# Why can questions only be migrated to the meta site of the main site?

Tags: support, migration, privileges

Sometimes there are questions asked on a site, but never belong to this site, **and** are a very good fit for another site. In such cases I would like to vote to migrate this question to the site it fits. However, I can't see such option. For example, [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124614/is-it-safe-to-check-personal-accounts-in-work-computer) Workplace.SE question fits Security.SE (or perhaps Stack Overflow?), but I can only vote to migrate this question to the corresponding meta site. Is this intentional? Do I not have the privileges to do this? I can't see such a privilege among the [privileges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

I am not sure whether it is a bug, something intentional or was not yet implemented, so I am tagging this as [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: I suspect that the choice of migration destinations in the flag dialog is based on what the moderators feel are _likely_ "cross-site confusion" destinations. For anything else, either flag it as off-topic/blatantly-off-topic and post a comment to the user that it might be better posted in {othersite}, or flag it for moderator attention and suggest that it be migrated to {othersite}. Note that the latter has not, in my experience, been often successful.

Comment: How do you know this would be well received on security.se? I don't think it would fly on Stack Overflow for instance and that's rather why general migration is not permitted, people would migrate things inappropriately to sites that don't want it.

Comment: @Robert Longson it is true that questions will get migrated inappropriately. That is why I am not referring to a migrate, but a **vote to migrate** option.

Answer (score 1):

The number of questions from main sites that get migrated to meta sites is fairly low. The number of those that would be worth migrating from one meta site to another is even lower.

Given the relative infrequency of questions like this, it wouldn't make sense to add that to the standard interface. Instead, a custom flag to a moderator asking for migration (again, if migration is even the appropriate action) is the way to handle this. Moderators can migrate to any meta site, and this is such an infrequent case that it doesn't add much to our workflow to flag these.

Answer (score 1):

Questions asked on main that belong on that site's meta are a common-enough use case to support a built-in migration path.  A few sites also have migration paths to other sites; for example, Writing has a migration option for English Language & Usage.  But the close/migrate menu is set up to give options, not to let you name an arbitrary site.  So, to answer the specific question, there aren't *enough* migrations from Workplace to Security to justify setting up a migration path.

Moderators, however, can migrate questions to any other site.  You can -- *only if the question is off-topic where it was asked* -- use a custom flag to suggest a migration, or leave a comment pointing out the other site.

Migrations have a couple inherent problems.  They can be pretty confusing for new users, especially when they're rejected by the other site -- the UX here is pretty bad.  We also often see suggestions to migrate questions "because they would do better on another site", which is unfair to the community where the question was asked.  I don't think SE is going to open up "migrate anywhere" to close-voters in general; doing so would exacerbate these problems.